# How can I show the images that I uploaded using Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, upload, show

I uploaded some images using Laravel taking help from this website 
https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-57-image-upload-with-validation-example

```
<img src='{{ asset('public\images\1565507900.jpg')}}'  width="400" height="400">
```

But I failed to show the images in the home page. How to do this?

Comment: The asset string `public\images\1565507900.jpg` should have forward characters, even on Windows. I would guess also that from the perspective of the docroot, it cannot see the public folder, so it probably should be `images/1565507900.jpg`. What HTML does this generate, when you "view source" in your browser?

Comment: could you show us the public folder in your project

Comment: why I can not put image in the comment for you to show my project I using php in laravel I need to upload the project logo I entered image in to the project by using this steps https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-57-image-upload-with-validation-example   and now the image saved in the public\images\1565507900.jpg I used this  command <img src='{{ asset('public\images\1565507900.jpg')}}'  width="400" height="400"> to appear the images in the home page but the browser just show the box of image

Comment: show me you gmail I  well send the project image for you

Comment: Read up [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem) - it walks you through the **proper** steps on uploading / retrieving files

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img src='{{ asset('images\1565507900.jpg')}}'  width="400" height="400">
```

Comment: I try this way but failed to show the image logo in the home page

Comment: show me you gmail I well send the project image for you

Comment: Look at this youtube video and Bitfumes will go it through step by step https://youtu.be/7ZGFWvunoxw